# Extract unique values from a column in one sheet and place them in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of strings in a column. I would like to take the unique values from this column and place them in another worksheet. I tried this but can't seem to get it to work.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A1048576").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2"), Unique:=True
```

The ":=" gives me an error each time.

Comment: I'm a scrub when it comes to stack overflow

Comment: I ask tough questions

Comment: Maybe, but I saw you received tough answers from highly valuable members.

Comment: Is your Column Titles in row 2?  if not you need to include them in the ranges.

Comment: I made the column titles first in another sheet, now I am trying to extract unique values from the other sheet

Comment: You still need to include them in the ranges.

Comment: BTW, did you see that I added vba to my answer on your last question?

Comment: Yes I did see that. It is just way beyond my scope of VB. I appreciate it.

Comment: @user11803068 Once you try my answer don't hesitate to leave me feedbacks if needed so I can improve it.

Comment: I did leave some feedback underneath the answer